# ps showing processes that can't possibly be running?

Tags: process, proxmox

Not sure if this is proxmox related, but when I run `ps aux` I see a bunch of processes running with uid 100000 (some higher) and some are for processes that involve a shell script that doesn't even exist anymore on the filesystem.

How? Why?

I have never seen this on other systems.

I tried killing the processes and rebooting but every time I reboot they come back as if they are being 'phantom-run' from some init script that I cannot find.

I did run these scripts a couple of weeks ago from that location but I've moved them to a different place and these processes should-just-not-run anymore.

snippet from ps aux:

```
100033      2300  0.0  0.1 225156 12552 ?  S    20:21   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start 
100000      2347  0.0  0.1  99964  9740 ?  Ss   20:21   0:00 /sbin/init 
100000      2361  0.0  0.0   2484   572 ?  S    20:21   0:00 /bin/sh /home/cap/bin/scripts/script1.sh 
100000      2362  0.0  0.0   2484   512 ?  S    20:21   0:00 /bin/sh /home/cap/bin/scripts/script2.sh
```

there are plenty of processes with valid uid values, but this one got me stumped.

Any ideas?

Edit: changed wording from PID to UID.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is exactly how processes from unprivileged containers should look like in the `ps` running on the host.

Proxmox has a possibility to run unprivileged LXC containers. What makes them unprivileged is UID mapping; Proxmox is configured so it adds 100000 to the in-container UID to get the mapped in-host UID. So, whatever you see on the host as 100000 is container's 0 (root), what you see 100033 is 33 in some container and so on. Therefore container's root is nobody particular on the host, has no privileges and therefore harmless.

Comment: I don't know proxmox, but plain LXC can do those additions, but they are not simple additions of 100000, but mappings to the range specified for the user running that LXC guest in `/etc/subuid` (technically probably somewhere in the kernel, but that file is the typical place to configure it. As an example `ps` on by computer shows processes with uid 168537, subtracting 100000 would give a uid that doesn't exist on my machine, but subtracting 165536 (which is the minimum uid available to me) gives 3001, which corresponds to my uid on that guest.

Comment: Yes, I meant that such a high value UID is a strong sign of containerization in action. If you happen to see the LXC config Proxmox creates (on the fly), you'd see it really adds 100000, so I specifically said: "Proxmox is configured...". I know that other systems are free to set it up as they like, but inevitably there will be such big UIDs.